# Download using c# code

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

I am developing c# application, in which i am downloading package(zip file) from server machine.It was downloading properly, but recently our package data has got some changes which is flex application.And by using c# we are downloading it into c drive or d drive.

Now with the new package i am facing some problem as 
Unable to read data from the transport connection: An operation on a socket could not be performed because the system lacked sufficient buffer space or because a queue was full.

My code is below

```
byte[] packageData = null;
packageData = touchServerClient.DownloadFile("/packages/" + this.PackageName);
public byte[] DownloadFile(string url)
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(remoteSite.Url + url);
            try
            {
                request.Method = "GET";
                request.KeepAlive = false;                

                request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
                if (this.Cookies != null && this.Cookies.Count > 0)
                    request.CookieContainer.Add(this.Cookies);

                HttpWebResponse webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();                

                // Console.WriteLine(response.StatusDescription);

                Stream responseStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();

                int contentLength = Convert.ToInt32(webResponse.ContentLength);
                byte[] fileData = StreamToByteArray(responseStream, contentLength);                
                return fileData;
            }



public static byte[] StreamToByteArray(Stream stream, int initialLength)
        {
            // If we've been passed an unhelpful initial length, just
            // use 32K.
            if (initialLength < 1)
            {
                initialLength = 32768;
            }

            byte[] buffer = new byte[initialLength];
            int read = 0;

            int chunk;
            while ((chunk = stream.Read(buffer, read, buffer.Length - read)) > 0)
            {
                read += chunk;

                // If we've reached the end of our buffer, check to see if there's
                // any more information
                if (read == buffer.Length)
                {
                    int nextByte = stream.ReadByte();

                    // End of stream? If so, we're done
                    if (nextByte == -1)
                    {
                        return buffer;
                    }

                    // Nope. Resize the buffer, put in the byte we've just
                    // read, and continue
                    byte[] newBuffer = new byte[buffer.Length * 2];
                    Array.Copy(buffer, newBuffer, buffer.Length);
                    newBuffer[read] = (byte)nextByte;
                    buffer = newBuffer;
                    read++;
                }
            }
            // Buffer is now too big. Shrink it.
            byte[] ret = new byte[read];
            Array.Copy(buffer, ret, read);
            return ret;
        }
```

In the above function(StreamToByteArray) , i am getting error as
Unable to read data from the transport connection: An operation on a socket could not be performed because the system lacked sufficient buffer space or because a queue was full.

Please help me on this, coz i am not supposed to change the code also.

Thanks in advance
Sangita

Comment: How big is this file?  Maybe you are exhausting your available memory?

Comment: Have a look at [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_protocols/archive/2009/03/09/understanding-the-error-an-operation-on-a-socket-could-not-be-performed-because-the-system-lacked-sufficient-buffer-space-or-because-a-queue-was-full.aspx) and [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/557879/why-am-i-getting-this-socketexception-in-my-c-service/557902#557902) and see if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things to try:

- Wrap your stream handling in a `using` statement.

This will clean up that resource.

```
using (Stream responseStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream())
{
    int contentLength = Convert.ToInt32(webResponse.ContentLength);
    byte[] fileData = StreamToByteArray(responseStream, contentLength);
    return fileData;        
}
```

- Make sure there are no other heavy memory processes running on the same box. Particularly if they are making Socket-bound calls.
- Try upping the value of the `MaxUserPort` registry value. [Here is the article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/196271) if you didn't see the link provided in the comments.

Comment: I think you're right that not disposing the stream is the issue here.

Comment: It is the package file size problem, it is abve 60 mb.All my old packages are below 50,000 kb.It is downloading without any fail.

Comment: I think it is a problem with huge size.

Comment: Hmm... the only other recommendation I could make is to read in your data in smaller chunks. You won't see any real performance hit by looping through a few times with smaller read amounts.