# Program producing error when running in a VM

Tags: c#, virtual-machine, ioexception, socketexception

I have a C# service application which receives files via UDP and saves them into a local drive. The application runs fine on local OS, but when it's running from a VM I get these exceptions from the Socket lib and the IO lib.

```
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): An operation on a socket could not be performed because the system lacked sufficient buffer space or because a queue was full

System.IO.IOException: Insufficient quota to complete the requested service.
```

I've tested the disk space, but It's 80% free. Also the Ram on the VM is set to 2GB.
I've google but couldn't find much on this topic.

@ David Stratton: 
Info About the VM system:
Using ESXi 4.1 
Host OS windows 2003

@ Seth Noble 
Your right. The first exception happens when it's sending a packet to the source.
And the Second IO exception when it receives the packets to write to disk.

Comment: What type of VM?  Virtual PC, Oracle VirtualBox, another?  Each will have different limitations and that ***may*** be relevant.  See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/557879/why-am-i-getting-this-socketexception-in-my-c-sharp-service  I think that the answer there gives a hint to the issue you're having.  A VM is a bit more limited than a true machine in some regards, so you may need to look at the specific limitations of your virtualization platform.

Comment: Is the application giving the exception sending or receiving?  Your description sounds like its receiving, but that error is typically one you'd get for sending.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is only happening in thw VM it is most likely a issue with the implementation of some of the features of the actual VM software and it is safe to assume that it is not due to a programming mistake on your part.