# FluentFTP.FtpClient throwing SocketException on Connect()

Tags: c#, sockets

I have a console program that runs perpetually to process background jobs. Every day, it uploads files via FTP to other servers. After a while it will begin to fail to transfer files with:

> SocketException: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An operation on a socket could not be performed because the system lacked sufficient buffer space or because a queue was full

Rebooting the server solves the issue but it's annoying. Other answers (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/557879/why-am-i-getting-this-socketexception-in-my-c-sharp-service)) suggest maybe my sockets are not being closed after use but I would expect `FtpClient.Dispose()` to take care of this, since it does not expose a `.Close()` method. Here's my code:

```
using (FtpClient client = new FtpClient())
{
     client.Host = "ftp.host.com";
     client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(userName: "foo", password: "bar");
     client.Connect();
     client.UploadFile(localPath: localPath, remotePath: remotePath, overwrite: true);
     client.Disconnect();
}
```

Are there other possible causes for this error that I should investigate?

Comment: If connection are made and disposed in some sort of loop, with little time in between, there might not be enough time for the underlying layers to actually dispose of the Socket. Since your program runs continuously, you could try to re-use the `FtpClient` object, instead of disposing it, just connect/disconnect as needed.

Comment: Pretty sure only two FTP connections are made every 24 hours, but that's a good idea!